# Create object with generic class as list

Tags: c#, generics

I have this situation:

```
public class ExtResult<T>
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

//create list object:
List<ProductPreview> gridLines;
...
...
//At the end i would like to create object
ExtResult<gridLines> result = new ExtResult<gridLines>() { 
    Success = true, Msg = "", 
    Total=0, 
    Data = gridLines 
}
```

But I get an error:

> error: "cannot resolve gridLines"

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: "*What is correct way?*" - to do what? (and mostly likely the answer is to learn about generics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gridLines` is a variable, its type is `List<ProductPreview>` which you should use as the type parameter to `ExtResult<T>`:

```
ExtResult<List<ProductPreview>> result = new ExtResult<List<ProductPreview>>() { 
    Success = true, 
    Msg = "", 
    Total=0, 
    Data = gridLines 
};
```

Comment: Of course, thank you. I was mislead by some example :)

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a type as a generic argument, not a variable:

```
var result = new ExtResult<List<ProductPreview>> // not gridLines, but it's type
{ 
    Success = true,
    Msg = "",
    Total=0,
    Data = gridLines
}
```